# Using sed to extract result from diffstat

Tags: unix, diff, diffstat

I am trying to use sed to get the number of insertions/deletions from diff stat.
For example, diffstat gives something like "1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)".
How can I retrieve "2" from diffstat using sed? I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks for your time.

Figured out very simple solution-

```
sed 's|.*\s\(.*\)\sinsertion.*|\1|'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/.*, \(.*\) insertions.*/\1/'
```

Explanation: look for "[anything], [something] insertions[anything]" and replace it with [something].  Might want to pass the diffstat through grep first to isolate this one line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo "1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)" | sed -r 's/.*([0-9]+) insertion.*/\1/'
```